# Solve not behaving the way I expect

Tags: equation-solving

I have a function

```
T = 1.6;
N[function1[1/T, Emin[T, 10], 10]]
```

> `-0.896121`

which yields me number as a result. Now I wanted to turn things around and find the corresponding T given this result:

```
Clear[T]
Solve[function1[1/T, Emin[T, 10], 10] == -0.8961210067225618`, T]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean that you "don't have the value of `E`"? I don't see an `E` anywhere in your expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have assigned a value to `T`, that value gets substituted the `Solve` expression, reducing it to semantic nonsense. What `Solve` sees is

```
Solve[True, 1.6]
```

which, of course, can't be solved.

I will use a simple example to show what is happening.

```
x = 42;
Sqrt[x]
```

> `Sqrt[42]`

```
Solve[Sqrt[x] == Sqrt[42], x]
```

> `Solve[True, 42]`

There are several work-arounds. Here are two.

1st work-arounds; remove the value from `x`.

```
Clear[x]; Solve[Sqrt[x] == Sqrt[42], x]
```

> `{{x -> 42}}`

2nd work-around; use another variable that has no value.

```
Solve[Sqrt[u] == Sqrt[42], u]
```

> `{{u -> 42}}`

Comment: Sadly that is not it :( I cleared T. 
But either way even if not cleared I should get a result, but as I said the computation starts......and never ends. As if it were trapped in some loop...

Comment: @CatoMaths. This was certainly part of your problem and it needed to be cleared away first. That doesn't mean there aren't other reasons while `Solve` isn't working for you, but they depend on the details of your definitions of `function` and `Emin`, which you keep secret from us. So no further help is possible.